# ActionBar background is transparent?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've set a custom background for my application, and it seems that doing so has caused the ordinarily black background of my ActionBar to become transparent. This makes it difficult to work with the search field I plan on adding to it.

I've tried overriding this with the following:

```
<style name="app_theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/app_background</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/TransparentListView</item>
    <item name="android:expandableListViewStyle">@style/TransparentExpandableListView</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Mytheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

This does not seem to correct my issue. How can I ensure that my action bar is black like it should be?

Comment: I'm fairly new to SO, and I'm very open to being told why users feel my questions are not a good fit. If you take the time to downvote, please also take the time to show me how to improve my questions in the future.

Search returned nothing on the issue and I was unable to find anything on google, but this seems to be baked in behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can set action bar color like below:**

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3BB9FF")));
```

if you want transparent action bar then check this link:
    http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/

**Also you can try xml style**:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/action_bar_theme</item>
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#fff</item>
</style>

<style name="action_bar_theme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
<item name="android:background">#b3000000</item>
<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/action_bar_text</item>
</style>
```

Hope this will help....

Comment: Is there any way to do it using the XML? I'd prefer to keep my view distinct and separated.